# Is it appropriate to use a singleton class to keep track of user info?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns, authentication, singleton

I am working on an IOS application that requires a user to log in. It has a Master View Controller that checks to see if the user is already logged in. If not, it segues to another view controller that displays a log in prompt. When the user logs in there, the master view controller dismisses the log in view and displays information appropriate to the user that logged in.

The application also stores user credentials in a settings plist. If that information is present, the application attempts to log in with the stored credentials. If that succeeds the Master View controller loads user-appropriate info. If not, it segues to the log in view controller.

I ended up duplicating the code in the Master View and Log in View controllers that verifies user id and password. Then, I need to pass the user instance in the prepareforsegue method to any subsequent view.

Should I implement a singleton class to keep track of the logged in user? It's tempting, because it seems like it could save a lot of work. Would it be better to delegate the user log in method I'm using in the Log In View controller back to the Master View Controller and pass the user instance in prepareforsegue each time I push a new view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I implement a singleton class to keep track of the logged in user?

You can certainly do that. However, you could also make a stateless helper class that reads credentials from the backing store as needed, avoiding the need to create a singleton.

> I ended up duplicating the code in the Master View and Log in View controllers

A stateless helper approach (i.e. a class with only class `(+)` methods in it) would prevent code duplication: the code that you ended up duplicating would go into the shared helper class.

> The application also stores user credentials in a settings plist.

If unencrypted password is part of user credentials, this is not a secure solution. You should use [*keychain services*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html) to save credentials in protected storage.

Comment: I also think it's worth touching on 'I ended up duplicating the code'. Anytime someone realizes that is a chance for them to rethink their code and make improvements.

Comment: dasblinkenlight: Thank you! Your advice set me on the right path. I appreciate it.